# UWSGI option log-drain missing when running in virtualenv

Tags: uwsgi, python-wheel

I have installed pyuwsgi=2.0.21 inside an application's virtualenv. I need to filter logs generated by uwsgi, so I decided to use --log-drain option. But when I checked uwsgi --help | grep drain that option was missing. I tried to replicate it outside the application's venev, so I created a venv outside and log-drain option was present. Could anyone help?

PS: In the application packages are installed from wheel file.
Below is wheel tag of pyuwsgi outside the application venv:
Wheel-Version: 1.0
Generator: bdist_wheel (0.29.0)
Root-Is-Purelib: false
Tag: cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64

Below is wheel tag of pyuwsgi in application's venv:
Wheel-Version: 1.0
Generator: bdist_wheel (0.33.6)
Root-Is-Purelib: false
Tag: cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64

I tried to replicate issue by creating venv outside application's venv and log-drain option was present.